# I have trouble building codes for frequency table in Huffman Compression

Tags: assembly

I am trying build frequency table for my Huffman compression. I do know how to make a compression tree but if i have to build codes for in assembly program, i get completely lost. Can anyone help me in build frequency table for Huffman compression in assembly language?

Comment: You should post some of your code and explain what you've already tried. Otherwise, this question is going to downvote hell

Comment: Could you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: 30 years ago I wrote on in IBM/370 assembler. It was really fun. Maybe I can find the tape where it had been stored.

Comment: Thank you. This will be really helpful. Based on code levels i haven't did it because i don't know where to start

Comment: yes we do not care about quality right now. it should just compress, even a little is good enough

Comment: yes i can do it with arrays

Comment: i actually have to do it with arrays

Comment: Hey, H.N., I just edited my answer to add my code for the compressor. When I finish the decompressor I will append it.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. Looking forward for decompressor and see how it works :)

Comment: i will wait for you decompression codes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, dear H.N., there is a poor implementation of Huffman algorithm with arrays, not trees at all. I know it works because I used it for a homework in good old Pascal (not as old as Thomas Kilian), it's very simple:

**Step 1 :** count all characters in the file you want to compress, put the characters and their counters in arrays and sort them in DESCENDING order (the most frequent char the first, the least frequent the last). Example:

[image]

**Step 2 :** assign Huffman codes for each character in a uniform way : every character gets a bit 1, and as many zeroes as its position, the first character gets the code 10, the second, 100, the third 1000, and so on. Next image shows the equivalent code if we would be using a tree:

[image]

Notice the previous tree is just the implementation of an array, that's why we can use arrays to generate Huffman codes. Don't get nervous, we are not using trees, it's just to illustrate our point.

The rest is ancient history: convert the ones and zeroes in bits inside bytes and store the bytes in the resulting (and not too much compressed) file.

**Extremely important :** save the Huffman codes and the characters they represent at the beginning of the file as strings. For example: C=10,E=100,R=1000,A=10000. We will need it to decompress our files.

Now decompression. Let's see how the word "ARE" was compressed :

```
ARE = 100001000100
```

It's easy to decode uniform Huffman codes because bits 1 are the delimiters, they mark the beginning of each Huffman code and the character they represent. The algorithm is simple:

1. Find a 1 bit.
2. Read zeroes until you reach another 1 or the end.
3. Find the code in the Huffman table (at the beginning of the file).
4. Store the char in the decompressed file.

**Remember**, this is a poor implementation of Huffman, but it works. The compression level depends on the character frequencies.

I'm not sure if I explained everything well. Questions?

**EDIT :** Oh yes! Almost forgot : the last Huffman code won't probably fill the last byte, so fill it with 1 bits with no zeroes. We will ignore consecutive 1 because we know consecutive 1 are just fillers (valid codes are 1 followed by zeroes, not 1 followed by 1).

**ASSEMBLY 8086 CODE FOR THE COMPRESSOR**

Next code was made with EMU8086. First, ask the user for the name of the file to compress and the name of the compressed file, then count all chars filling the array of frequencies, sort the arrays in descending order, save the array of chars in the compressed file, and, finally, reads each char from the source file and store the huffman codes in the other file. The compression level can be good or bad depending on the characters frequencies: if many characters repeat the same number of times, compression will be bad (the file might be bigger than the original), if most of characters repeat different number of times, compression is better (smaller than original). **Warning** : this is a 8086 program, it can not handle files bigger than 64 Kb (65535 bytes) because the counters are 16 bits (0..65535), it may compress bigger files, as long as none of its bytes repeat more than 65535 times (which is hard to know), maybe in the future I will post the 64 bits version.

```
.model small
.stack 100h

;-----------------------------------------

.data

char_array   db 256 dup(?) ;ARRAY FOR ASCII CHARACTERS.
freq_array   dw 256 dup(0) ;ARRAY OF FREQUENCIES OF EACH ASCII CHARACTER. 
msj1         db 13,10,'Enter name of file to compress: $'
filenameS    db 99        ;MAX NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ALLOWED (98).
             db ?         ;LENGTH (NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ENTERED BY USER).
             db 99 dup(0) ;CHARACTERS ENTERED BY USER. END WITH CHR(13).
filehandlerS dw ?         ;SOURCE HANDLER.
msj2         db 13,10,'Enter name of compressed file : $'
filenameD    db 99        ;MAX NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ALLOWED (98).
             db ?         ;LENGTH (NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ENTERED BY USER).
             db 99 dup(0) ;CHARACTERS ENTERED BY USER. END WITH CHR(13).
filehandlerD dw ?         ;DESTINATION HANDLER.
msj3         db 13,10,'The file was compressed.$'
the_char     db ?
i            dw ?
j            dw ?
mask0        db 11111110b ;USED TO SET BITS IN 0 WITH AND.
             db 11111101b
             db 11111011b
             db 11110111b
             db 11101111b
             db 11011111b
             db 10111111b
             db 01111111b
mask1        db 00000001b ;USED TO SET BITS IN 1 WITH OR.
             db 00000010b
             db 00000100b
             db 00001000b
             db 00010000b
             db 00100000b
             db 01000000b
             db 10000000b
the_byte     db ?         ;BYTE FILLED WITH HUFFMAN BITS.

;-----------------------------------------

.code
start:

;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax                 

  call get_source_file        ;FILE TO COMPRESS.
  call get_destination_file   ;COMPRESSED FILE.
  call fill_chars             ;FILL CHAR_ARRAY WITH 256 ASCII CHARS.
  call count_chars            ;FILL FREQ_ARRAY WITH FREQUENCIES OF CHARS.
  call bubble_sort_descending ;SORT FREQ_ARRAY AND CHAR_ARRAY.
  call huffman_file           ;READ EACH CHAR AND SAVE ITS HUFFMAN CODE.  

;WAIT FOR ANY KEY.    
  mov  ah, 7
  int  21h

;FINISH PROGRAM.
  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h

;-----------------------------------------

get_source_file proc
;DISPLAY MESSAGE.
  mov dx, offset msj1
  mov ah, 9
  int 21h      

;CAPTURE FILENAME FROM KEYBOARD.                                    
  mov ah, 0Ah
  mov dx, offset filenameS
  int 21h                

;CAPTURED STRING ENDS WITH CHR(13), BUT FILES REQUIRE
;THE FILENAME TO END WITH CHR(0), SO LET'S CHANGE IT.
  mov si, offset filenameS + 1 ;STRING LENGTH.
  mov cl, [ si ]        ;MOVE LENGTH TO CL.
  mov ch, 0             ;CLEAR CH TO USE CX. 
  inc cx                ;ONE MORE BYTE TO REACH CHR(13).
  add si, cx            ;NOW SI POINTS TO CHR(13).
  mov al, 0
  mov [ si ], al        ;REPLACE CHR(13) BY 0.

  ret
get_source_file endp

;-----------------------------------------

get_destination_file proc
;DISPLAY MESSAGE.
  mov dx, offset msj2
  mov ah, 9
  int 21h      

;CAPTURE FILENAME FROM KEYBOARD.                                    
  mov ah, 0Ah
  mov dx, offset filenameD
  int 21h                

;CAPTURED STRING ENDS WITH CHR(13), BUT FILES REQUIRE
;THE FILENAME TO END WITH CHR(0), SO LET'S CHANGE IT.
  mov si, offset filenameD + 1 ;STRING LENGTH.
  mov cl, [ si ]        ;MOVE LENGTH TO CL.
  mov ch, 0             ;CLEAR CH TO USE CX. 
  inc cx                ;ONE MORE BYTE TO REACH CHR(13).
  add si, cx            ;NOW SI POINTS TO CHR(13).
  mov al, 0
  mov [ si ], al        ;REPLACE CHR(13) BY 0.

  ret
get_destination_file endp

;-----------------------------------------
;FILL ARRAY OF CHARS WITH ASCII CHARS 0..255.

fill_chars proc
  mov  si, offset char_array
  mov  cx, 0
filling:      
  mov  [ si ], cl
  inc  si
  inc  cx
  cmp  cx, 255
  jbe  filling

  ret
fill_chars endp    

;-----------------------------------------
;READ ALL CHARACTERS FROM FILE INCREASING THE COUNTER OF
;EACH CHARACTER IN THE ARRAY OF FREQUENCIES. EACH CHARACTER
;IS USED AS THE OFFSET OF ITS OWN COUNTER, EXAMPLE: THE
;COUNTER FOR 'A' IS THE POSITION 65 OF FREQ_ARRAY.

count_chars proc
;OPEN FILE.
  mov  ah, 3dh          ;SERVICE TO OPEN FILE.
  mov  al, 0            ;OPEN AS READ ONLY.
  mov  dx, offset filenameS + 2
  int  21h  
  mov  filehandlerS, ax ;NECESSARY FOR OPERATIONS ON FILE.

;COUNT CHARACTERS.
reading:  
;READ ONE CHAR FROM FILE.
  mov  ah, 3fh          ;SERVICE TO READ FROM FILE.
  mov  bx, filehandlerS
  mov  cx, 1            ;HOW MANY BYTES TO READ.
  mov  dx, offset the_char ;WHERE TO STORE THE READ BYTES.  
  int  21h
;CHECK END OF FILE.
  cmp  ax, 0
  je   end_reading      ;IF READ ZERO BYTES, FINISH.
;INCREASE COUNTER. THE CHAR ITSELF IS BEEN USES AS INDEX: THE
;COUNTER FOR CHAR 65 ('A') IS IN THE 65th POSITION OF THE ARRAY.
  mov  si, offset freq_array
  mov  al, the_char     ;USE CHAR AS OFFSET OF ITS OWN COUNTER.
  mov  ah, 0            ;CLEAR AH TO USE AX.
  shl  ax, 1            ;AX * 2, BECAUSE EVERY COUNTER IS 2 BYTES.
  add  si, ax           ;SI POINTS TO COUNTER POSITION.
  inc  [ word ptr si ]
  jmp  reading

end_reading:           
;CLOSE FILE.
  mov  ah, 3eh          ;SERVICE TO CLOSE FILE.
  mov  bx, filehandlerS  
  int  21h

  ret
count_chars endp

;-----------------------------------------
;SORT BOTH ARRAYS (FREQ_ARRAY AND CHAR_ARRAY) IN
;DESCENDING ORDER.
;for ( i = 0; i < len-1; i++ )
;  for ( j = i+1; j < len; j++ )
;    if ( arr[i] < arr[j] ) // '<' BECAUSE IT'S ASCENDING.
;      exchange

bubble_sort_descending proc
  mov  i, 0             ;I = 0.
fori:
  mov  ax, i            ;AX = I.
  inc  ax               ;I++.
  mov  j, ax            ;J = I++.
forj:
;GET FREQ[ I ].
  mov  si, offset freq_array
  mov  ax, i
  shl  ax, 1            ;I * 2, BECAUSE EVERY COUNTER IS 2 BYTES.
  add  si, ax
  mov  ax, [ si ]       ;AX = FREQ[ I ].
;GET FREQ[ J ].
  mov  di, offset freq_array
  mov  cx, j
  shl  cx, 1            ;J * 2, BECAUSE EVERY COUNTER IS 2 BYTES.
  add  di, cx
  mov  cx, [ di ]       ;CX = FREQ[ J ].
;IF ( FREQ[ I ] < FREQ[ J ] ).
  cmp  ax, cx           ;CMP FREQ[ I ], FREQ[ J ].
  jae  bigger           ;IF ( FREQ[I] >= FREQ[J] ) NO EXCHANGE.
;EXCHANGE BECAUSE FREQ[ I ] IS NOT BIGGER THAN FREQ[ J ].
  ;EXCHANGE COUNTERS IN FREQ_ARRAY.
    mov  [ si ], cx     ;FREQ[ I ] = FREQ[ J ].
    mov  [ di ], ax     ;FREQ[ J ] = FREQ[ I ].
  ;EXCHANGE CHARACTERS IN CHAR_ARRAY.
    ;GET CHAR[ I ].
      mov  si, offset char_array
      add  si, i        ;DON'T NEED SHL, BECAUSE EVERY CHAR IS 1 BYTE.         
      mov  al, [ si ]   ;AL = CHAR[ I ].
    ;GET CHAR[ J ].
      mov  di, offset char_array
      add  di, j        ;DON'T NEED SHL, BECAUSE EVERY CHAR IS 1 BYTE. 
      mov  ah, [ di ]   ;AH = CHAR[ J ].
    ;EXCHANGE.
      mov  [ si ], ah   ;CHAR[ I ] = CHAR[ J ].
      mov  [ di ], al   ;CHAR[ J ] = CHAR[ I ].
bigger:
;NEXT J.
  inc  j                ;J++.
  cmp  j, 255
  jbe  forj             ;IF ( J <= 255 ) REPEAT.  
;NEXT I.
  inc  i                ;I++.
  cmp  i, 255
  jb   fori             ;IF ( I <  255 ) REPEAT.  

  ret
bubble_sort_descending endp    

;-----------------------------------------
;READ EACH CHARACTER FROM SOURCE FILE, AND STORE THE
;HUFFMAN CODE OF EACH CHARACTER IN DESTINATION FILE.

huffman_file proc
;OPEN SOURCE FILE.
  mov  ah, 3dh          ;SERVICE TO OPEN FILE.
  mov  al, 0            ;OPEN AS READ ONLY.
  mov  dx, offset filenameS + 2
  int  21h  
  mov  filehandlerS, ax ;NECESSARY FOR OPERATIONS ON FILE.

;CREATE DESTINATION FILE.
  mov  ah, 3ch          ;SERVICE TO CREATE FILE.
  mov  cx, 0            ;NO ATTRIBUTES.
  mov  dx, offset filenameD + 2
  int  21h         
  mov  filehandlerD, ax ;NECESSARY FOR OPERATIONS ON FILE.

  call save_chars       ;SAVE ARRAY OF CHARS AT FILE'S BEGIN-.
                        ;NING, NECESSARY TO DECOMPRESS.
;CODIFY CHARACTERS.         
  mov  bp, 0            ;START SAVING BITS IN BIT 0.
                                                                       mov di,0
codifying:  
;READ ONE CHAR FROM SOURCE FILE.
  mov  ah, 3fh          ;SERVICE TO READ FROM FILE.
  mov  bx, filehandlerS
  mov  cx, 1            ;HOW MANY BYTES TO READ.
  mov  dx, offset the_char ;WHERE TO STORE THE READ BYTES.  
  int  21h
;CHECK END OF FILE.
  cmp  ax, 0
  je   end_codifying    ;IF READ ZERO BYTES, FINISH.

  call huffman_char     ;CODIFY CHAR, SAVE CODE TO DESTINATION FILE.
                                                                       inc di
  jmp  codifying        ;REPEAT PROCESS FOR NEXT CHAR.

end_codifying:                                                      
  call last_byte        ;IF LAST BYTE WAS NOT FULL, FILL IT.

;CLOSE FILES.
  mov  ah, 3eh
  mov  bx, filehandlerD  
  int  21h
  mov  ah, 3eh
  mov  bx, filehandlerS  
  int  21h

  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset msj3
  int  21h

  ret
huffman_file endp

;-----------------------------------------
;WRITES TO FILE THE ARRAY OF CHARS. NECESSARY TO
;DECOMPRESS THE FILE. THE CHARS ARE SAVED IN DESCENDING
;ORDER, THIS WAY WE KNOW FIRST CHAR TAKES CODE 10, NEXT
;IS 100, ETC. SAVING THE CHARS TAKES LESS BYTES THAN
;STORING THE 256 HUFFMAN CODES, BECAUSE THE FIRST CODE
;IS 10, NEXT 100, ETC., THE TOTAL 256 CODES ARE: FIRST
;CODE IS 1 ZERO, NEXT IS 2 ZEROES, LAST IS 256 ZEROES,
;FORMULA: (N*(N+1))/2 = (256*(256+1))/2 = 32.896 ZEROES,
;PLUS ONE '1' PER CODE = 256 '1', SO, THE TOTAL SIZE FOR
;256 HUFFMAN CODES IS = 32.896 + 256 = 33.152. COMPARE
;THIS NUMBER WITH THE SIZE OF THE ARRAY = 256 BYTES.

save_chars proc
  mov  ah, 40h           ;SERVICE TO WRITE ON FILE.
  mov  bx, filehandlerD  ;FILE.
  mov  dx, offset char_array ;DATA TO WRITE.
  mov  cx, 256           ;DATA SIZE IN BYTES.
  int  21h

  ret
save_chars endp

;-----------------------------------------
;BUILD HUFFMAN CODE FOR CHAR "THE_CHAR". IF CODE REQUIRES
;MORE THAN ONE BYTE, BYTES ARE BEEN WRITTEN WHILE THEY ARE
;FILLED. THE STARTING BIT IS INDICATED BY BP.
;AFTER FINISH, THE NEXT BIT TO USE IS INDICATED BY BP. FOR
;EXAMPLE, THE FIRST CHAR STARTS AT BIT 0, IF ITS CODE IS
;"1000", BP WILL BE 4 (POSITION FOR NEXT CODE), IF CODE
;WOULD BE "100000000" (9 BITS), A FULL BYTE WILL BE FILLED,
;WILL BE STORED TO DESTINATION FILE, AND ONE BIT OF ANOTHER
;BYTE WILL BE USED, SO BP WILL BE "1".

huffman_char proc    
;SET BIT 1 (ALL HUFFMAN CODES START WITH 1 AND N ZEROES).
  mov  si, offset mask1 ;ARRAY WITH 8 MASKS TO SET BITS IN 1.
  add  si, bp           ;SI POINTS TO MASK TO SET BIT BP IN 1.
  mov  al, [ si ]       ;AL = MASK TO SET BIT BP IN 1.
  or   the_byte, al     ;SET BIT BP (0..7) IN 1.
  inc  bp               ;NEXT BIT TO SET.
;CHECK IF BYTE IS FULL.
  cmp  bp, 7
  jbe  not_full1        ;IF ( BP <= 7 ) BYTE IS NOT FULL.
  call write_byte       ;BYTE IS FULL. SAVE IT TO FILE.  

not_full1:
;SET BITS 0 (ALL HUFFMAN CODES START WITH 1 AND N ZEROES).
;WE NEED AS MANY 0 AS THE POSITION OF THE CHAR, PLUS 1 (CHAR
;0 GETS 1 ZERO, CHAR 1 GETS 2 ZEROES, ETC.).
  mov  al, the_char     ;CHAR BEEN CODIFIED.
  call find_char        ;RETURNS POSITION OF CHAR IN CX.
  inc  cx               ;POSITION+1 ZEROES.  
zeroes:
;SET BIT 0 (ALL HUFFMAN CODES START WITH 1 AND N ZEROES).
  mov  si, offset mask0 ;ARRAY WITH 8 MASKS TO SET BITS IN 0.
  add  si, bp           ;SI POINTS TO MASK TO SET BIT BP IN 0.
  mov  al, [ si ]       ;AL = MASK TO SET BIT BP IN 0.
  and  the_byte, al     ;SET BIT BP (0..7) IN 0.
  inc  bp               ;NEXT BIT TO SET.
;CHECK IF BYTE IS FULL.
  cmp  bp, 7
  jbe  not_full0        ;IF ( BP <= 7 ) BYTE IS NOT FULL.
  push cx               ;PRESERVE CX BECAUSE "WRITE_BYTE" MODIFY IT.
  call write_byte       ;BYTE IS FULL. SAVE IT TO FILE.                 
  pop  cx               ;RESTORE CX.
not_full0:                                               
  loop zeroes           ;CX-1. IF ( CX > 0 ) REPEAT.

  ret
huffman_char endp

;-----------------------------------------
;WHEN ONE BYTE IS FILLED WITH BITS, IT IS WRITTEN on
;DESTINATION FILE.

write_byte proc
  mov  ah, 40h           ;SERVICE TO WRITE ON FILE.
  mov  bx, filehandlerD  ;FILE.
  mov  dx, offset the_byte ;DATA TO WRITE.
  mov  cx, 1             ;DATA SIZE IN BYTES.
  int  21h

  mov  bp, 0             ;NEXT BYTE STARTS AT BIT 0.

  ret
write_byte endp

;-----------------------------------------
;PARAMETER : AL = CHAR TO FIND.
;RETURNS   : CX = CHAR POSITION IN ARRAY (0..).

find_char proc
  mov  si, offset char_array ;SI = POINTER TO ARRAY.
  mov  cx, 0            ;START POSITION.
finding:                ;COUNTER.
  cmp  [ si ], al   
  je   found            ;IF ( CURRENTCHAR == CHARTOFIND ) FINISH.
  inc  si               ;INCREASE POINTER.               
  inc  cx               ;INCREASE POINTER.
  cmp  cx, 255                    
  jbe  finding          ;IF ( COUNTER <= 255 ) REPEAT. 
found:  
  ret
find_char endp

;-----------------------------------------
;FILLS THE LAST BYTE WITH 1s.

last_byte proc
  cmp  bp, 0
  je   no_last_byte     ;IF ( BP == 0 ) THERE IS NO NEED OF LAST BYTE.

;FILL LAST BYTE WITH 1.    
fill1:
;SET BIT 1.
  mov  si, offset mask1 ;ARRAY WITH 8 MASKS TO SET BITS IN 1.
  add  si, bp           ;SI POINTS TO MASK TO SET BIT BP IN 1.
  mov  al, [ si ]       ;AL = MASK TO SET BIT BP IN 1.
  or   the_byte, al     ;SET BIT BP (0..7) IN 1.
  inc  bp               ;NEXT BIT TO SET.
;CHECK IF BYTE IS FULL.
  cmp  bp, 7
  jbe  fill1            ;IF ( BP <= 7 ) BYTE IS NOT FULL.

  call write_byte       ;BYTE IS FULL. SAVE IT TO FILE.  

no_last_byte:

  ret
last_byte endp

;-----------------------------------------

end start
```

Comment: With all due respect, what you are describing here is a (not very efficient, but you knew that) compression method, which uses a binary unique suffix encoding of each character. It is, however, not Huffman. Huffman compression specifically means to allocate an optimal (in terms of the compression that can be achieved) bit encoding of the symbols based on their frequencies.

Comment: The misuse of terminology is mentioned in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_code): `Huffman coding is such a widespread method for creating prefix codes that the term "Huffman code" is widely used as a synonym for "prefix code" even when such a code is not produced by Huffman's algorithm.` This is a prefix code, but not a Huffman code.

Comment: This algorithm will get him a 0 on his assignment because it is not Huffman. Coding a Huffman algorithm, because it is not trivial, is probably why he was asked to create it. My guess is this is a mid-term type assignment that is due soon :)

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez - that's not the point and you know it.  And with all due respect, I see no assembly in your above post either.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding - with pretty graphics and everything.  Don't think this is quite what you wanted though.  Perhaps:https://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/video/mpeg/mpegfaq/huffman_tutorial.html  Or any other googles.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am about to try this, let see if it works for me

Comment: When you open the compressed file, remember it has the array of characters at the beginning, so the compressed file starts with the 256 ASCII characters (sorted in descending order), after these 256 bytes you will get the compressed codes, but, because the codes are bits, you will not see them, you will see bytes. To see the bits you will need a little program that I posted here (don't use HxD, use the other answer, my answer) = http://superuser.com/questions/463906/how-to-see-all-the-bits-of-a-file